# Is it possible to add a time zone offset to Microsoft Oulook "Sent" header?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I use Microsoft Outlook 2016 from Windows 10 at a large, global corporation.

At the office, I work on a global team.  It is common to have a long email chain where replies are sent from a variety of time zones.  Unfortunately, the "Sent" field in each reply is missing time zone offset.

Is it possible to configure Outlook (or Exchange Server) to add a time zone to the "Sent" field when a reply is created?

To be clear, I find all of the original emails and look at their MIME headers to know the exact time zone offset.  However, it is too much work.

One idea: It might be possible to write a VBA macro that will create a new reply where the Sent header is modified to include current time zone.  The downside: This requires everyone to use the VBA macro -- very unlikely.

I found this Microsoft support reply; it does not look possible:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/adding-timezone-code-in-email-reply-timestamp/e1ab17bc-ca45-4c70-983a-7f8c90f8ee44

Comment: I am confused. The time you received the email is displayed in the each recipient’s system time zone. Why is it important to adjust the time zone?

Comment: @Ramhound: Think about a long email chain with replies from multiple time zones.  When you are reviewing the latest email with full chain, each "Sent" will *not* have a time zone.  It is just plain text, so Outlook cannot magically update to your current time zone.

Comment: My comment was from 8 months ago. I stand by my comment, I am still confused, by the problem set. The author never improved their question. I deal with users in another time zone daily by email. I personally never care to know when it was sent by the sender, only when I received it, so my confusion is my own but up to the author to explain their problem set